# How to use custom fields globally in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, global-variables, custom-post-type, custom-fields

I'm trying to use the value of one custom field on multiple pages and posts. I'm a newbie to PHP and custom fields so what I'm trying to accomplish could possible be done using a different method.

I have a WPMU setup with all new sites created from a default blog that includes multiple custom post type templates. When users create a new site they are redirected to their site admin dashboard.

Here comes my challenge, I want users to be able to enter information into form fields contained in metabox(es) on their admin dashboard (not post editor) that will be used on the various custom post type templates. For example, a user will need to enter their company name, address, logo, etc.

Depending on the temple, the information entered into the form fields will be used on the frontend of the site. For example, the company logo will be display where the custom field or shortcode is placed on the post template.

I'm having issues using custom fields for this because each custom field is specific to each post. In addition, I'm having issues rendering a form on the admin dashboard for this.

I'm also thinking that custom fields may not be the best way to accomplish my objective because they are usually post specific. I'm really asking for a variable that will be used globally and is static unless the user updates the form.

I'd appreciate any assistance on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The options API is what you will need for this:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API

There's also some plugins and frameworks you can use to help such as:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/options-framework/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/redux-framework/

Comment: Read the codex page you shared and checked out the to plugin recommendations. It's just what I was looking for. Thanks for the assist.